# copying different ranges of cells in excel according to styling

Tags: vba, excel

Im using a pivot table to arrange my data. when I copy my data to another sheet its looks like that:
[image]

but I want the data to be one by the other like that:
[image]

how can I use the bold lines as headers and cut only the required ranges which are not fixed? I tried using macros but I could only copy fixed ranges so I'm doing it manually each time (and some om the sheets are pretty big).
please help,
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have full control on all the cells in the `PivotTable`. Sample code:

```
Dim curpivottable As PivotTable
Set curpivottable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Dim curRange As Range
Set curRange = curpivottable.TableRange1

For Each cell In curRange.Cells
    If (cell.Font.Bold) Then
       'This is a bold cell
    End If
Next cell
```

Bear in mind that `curRange` includes all the contents in `curpivottable`, from the first row (where the title is).

-- UPDATE

My answer above was the generic way to deal with ranges in PivotTables. If all what you want is just copying/pasting a range, you can do it directly (is the same if the range is in the PivotTable or not). Example:

```
Dim origRange As Range
Set origRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A500")
Dim destRange As Range
Set destRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
origRange.Copy
destRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Equivalently, you can check the format of the given cells (being bold or not) independently upon being inside a PivotTable or not.

Comment: Thanks but what does the If section do?, when I run in it nothing seems to happen. Do I need to copy the cells inside the IF?

Comment: @user1040563 nothing happens because nothing is written; there is just a comment. You have to write there your code to do whatever you want. From your question I understood that you know how to deal with ranges, what you have there is a range (cell) with a bold format and you can do whatever with it (extract information, change its contents/format, etc.).

Comment: @user1040563 I have updated my answer; please take a look at it and let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: @user1040563 please read all what is written in my updated answer, make your ideas completely clear and re-write your question such that the specific action you want to accomplish is perfectly defined. Example: I want to find the first bold range inside columns X-Y/PivotTable..., copy all the rows below it until ".." and paste all these cells into... Ideally, my answer should have been enough to help you to understand the situation a bit better, such that you will be able to write the code completely by your own.